# Can a different order of levels for a binary dependent variable change a random forest model?

Tags: r, binary, classification, random-forest

So I am working on a private dataset in R for my studies and we ran into the following problem:

We are using a Random Forest model to predict a binary dependent variable (customer_churn = (0, 1)). Midway through our project, we noticed that our PDP were producing the inverse relationships of what we expected in many cases. After some research, it turned out that our Random Forest model regarded [customer_churn == 0] as the positive value, which made our PDP calculate the relationship to the probability of [customer_churn == 0].

We solved this by setting the factor variable of our dependent variable to "customer_churn <- factor(customer_churn, levels = c(1,0)), setting 1 as the positive outcome value. The thing is, after rerunning our model, it seems like a lot has changed. Our model performance changes quite a bit (accuracy: 71% -> 76%, sensitivity: 76% -> 69%, specificity: 71%-> 77%), as well as our PD plots. Sensitivity and Specificity were indeed turned around beforehand, but we set the positive value in the confusion matrix to 1 manually, so the changes are indeed as stated. Even stranger to us, the PD plots show very different results, with some segments showing the same relationship as before, while other relationships were inversed.

Our expectation was that many things in our model would inverse after turning the factor levels around, but it seems like they have just changed drastically. We used many different seeds before in our analysis, and the changes in randomness had a much lower impact on our results than changing the factor levels around. Is this possible? If so, what does this mean?

Comment: How are you translating the probabilities output by the model into classifications? Are you using a threshold? If you assess the probabilities rather than the classification (e.g. with Brier scores) do you still see a difference?

Comment: In our used model we do not change the threshold; we keep this constant at the default 0.5. It is a good idea though to assess the probabilities rather than the classification. Thank you for the suggestion!